# Cannot read property 'api' of undefined angular while using nggride

Tags: angular, ng-grid

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub1',
  templateUrl: './sub1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub1.component.css']
})

export class Sub1Component implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('agGrid',{static: false} ) agGride:AgGridAngular

  columnDefs = [
    {headerName:'make',field: 
'make',sortable:true,filter:true,checkboxSelection:true },
    {headerName:'model',field: 'model',sortable:true,filter:true  },
    {headerName:'price',field: 'price',sortable:true,filter:true }
  ];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

  rowData :any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.rowData=this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/sample-data/smallRowData.json')
  }

  getRow(){
    const selectedNodes = this.agGride.api.getSelectedNodes();
    const selectedData = selectedNodes.map( node => node.data );
    const selectedDataStringPresentation = 
      selectedData.map(node => node.make + ' ' + node.model).join(', ');
    console.log(`Selected nodes: ${selectedDataStringPresentation}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The API is only available after initialization of the grid, so try to delay the call of `getRow()` method by listening to the `onGridReady()` event and there you can be sure that you have the `gridApi` and that u can use it.

To see if this is what causing you the issue, you can use setTimeOut on the getRow() method and see if that solves it. Otherwise, try to find check the docs for
how to get the API via initialization methods like `onGridReady`